# Dismiss WKWebView in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, navigation, swiftui, wkwebview

I'm new to Swift and building an application using SwiftUI.

I'm displaying a WKWebView using code that's similar to what I've written below.

```
struct SomeView: View {

    @State var showWebView = false

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Button(action: {
                self.showWebView.toggle()

            }) {
                Text("Go To WebView")
                    .padding()
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                    .font(.title)
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $showWebView, content: {
                WebView(url: "https://www.apple.com/")
            })
        }
    }
}

struct WebView: UIViewRepresentable {

    var url: String

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator()
    }

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        let webView = WKWebView()
        return webView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WebView.UIViewType, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<WebView>) {
        let urlRequest = URLRequest.init(url: URL.init(string: self.url)!)
        uiView.navigationDelegate = context.coordinator
        uiView.load(urlRequest)
    }
}

class Coordinator: NSObject, WKNavigationDelegate {

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction,
                 decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
        if let url = navigationAction.request.url?.absoluteString {
            if url.contains("apple") {
                let someViewModel = SomeViewModel()
                someViewModel.processRequest(url: url)
            }
        }
        decisionHandler(.allow)
    }
}
```

The code works as expected. I'm able to display a WKWebView showing the desired website. However, I'm struggling to figure out how to dismiss the WKWebView and navigate to another page once I've invoked `someViewModel.processRequest()`. Could you please assist?

Answer (score 4):

I would do the whole WebView thing a bit different, which should (as far as I understand your problem) solve your situation:

```
import SwiftUI
import SafariServices

struct SomeView: View {

    @State var showWebView = false

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Button(action: {
                self.showWebView.toggle()

            }) {
                Text("Go To WebView")
                    .padding()
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                    .font(.title)
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $showWebView, content: {
                WebView(url: URL(string: "https://www.apple.com/")!) })

        }
    }
}

struct WebView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

    let url: URL

    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<WebView>) -> SFSafariViewController {
        return SFSafariViewController(url: url)
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: SFSafariViewController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<WebView>) {
    }

}
```